# prove that there are no natural numbers for which $15x^2-7y^2=9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

my approach:

$15x^2-7y^2=9\implies y^2=(15x^2-9)/7$

$$\implies (14x^2-7+x^2-2)/7=(2x^2-1)+(x^2-2)/7$$

then I found that $x^2-2$ is divisible by $7$ only when it is of the form $7n\pm3,$

so then replaced $x$ by $7n\pm3$ over here $y^2=(15x^2-9)/7.$

so $y^2=15(49n^2\pm42n+7).$

here $y^2$ is possible only when both the roots are equal  which is possible only when the discriminant is $0$ ,so i tried and got the discriminant as $540$. so there is a non-zero discriminant,so no solution is possible.
Is my proof correct or am i going wrong ?

Comment: You have been around for two months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Both the roots of what? I don’t think that step is true.

Comment: Since $15x^2$ and $9$ are both divisible by $3$, $7y^2$ (and hence $y$) must also be divisible by $3$. So, write $y=3z$, and then the equation becomes $15x^2-63z^2=9$, which becomes $5x^2-21z^2=3$ after dividing by $3$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I am sorry if this is an awfully stupid question but how does converting my equation into that form solve it and also in my approach could you please specify where I am going wrong .....I am utterly confused.

Comment: Continuing with my previous comment, since $21z^2$ and $3$ are both divisible by $3$, $5x^2$ (and hence $x$) must also be divisible by $3$. So, write $x=3w$, and then the equation becomes $45w^2-21z^2=3$, which becomes $15w^2-7z^2=1$ after dividing by $3$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks a ton sir

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1583093 ;
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1756779 ; https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1784619

Answer (score 1):

continuing from $y^2=15(49n^2 \pm 42n+7)$,
$3\mid 49n^2+7$
$3\mid 7n^2+1$
$n^2\equiv 2\pmod{3}$
contradiction

Answer (score 1):

$15x^2-7y^2=9$.

3 must divide y since it divides all but the y term and doesn't divide 7. This implies the term with $x$ is divisible by 9, but 15 is only divisible by 3. It follows that x is also divisible by 3. Let y=3q and x=3p.

$135p^2-63q^2=9$

$15p^2-7q^2=1$

$3q^2\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

2 is the multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 5.

$q^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$

There is no such $q$, so we have a contradiction.